# Can we have more than one submit type button in one form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, submit

I need to implement validation for a form but by two submit buttons?

Can we do change the 'Type' from jQuery so that it can work perfectly as i want:)

Comment: You can, but only one button can be clicked at a time.

Comment: can you explain more what you wanna to do please?

Comment: @Akram @just_name :: my problem is i want to place more than one submit type input element in a single form and implement JQuery validate in every elements inside that form:) on any one of the button submit click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/06/using-multiple-forms-on-an-asp-net-web-forms-page/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/avi_sanjay/MultiForms.htm06042006062957AM/MultiForms.htm.aspx

Comment: why would you want to do that?..whts ur context?

Comment: To use a form validation with JQuery in asp.net form with more than one submit buttons place in one form field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about client-side validation you can use JavaScript to make different buttons post to different locations (these locations can be different to validate it in more than one way on the server side) e.g.

```
<form name="someForm1" id="someForm1" method="POST">
.
.
.


<input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" onclick="javascript:post1();"/>
<input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" onclick="javascript:post2();"/>
</form>
```

Then make **post1** implement one type of client-side validation (**validate1()**) and **post2** (**validate2()**) the other approach. You can even use JavaScript to post to different URLs. An example of how this can be done is:

```
function post1()
{
  var form1=document.forms['someForm1'];
  form1.action="form1.aspx";
  if(validate1())
  {
     form1.submit();
  }
  else
  {
     invalid1();
  }    
}
```

Comment: You suggesting for <input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" onclick="javascript:post1();"/>
<input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" onclick="javascript:post2();"/> which are button type but i am require to do same task with Submit type input :)

Comment: Making them submit types would submit them to the same location. That is why instead we make them normal buttons and use JavaScript to actually post the form.